# Possible error of volume - Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, volume

I'm trying to solve a problem using derivative.

The dimensions of a rectangular box are 5m, 6m and 8m. With a possible error of 0,01m in each dimension. 
Calculate the approximate value of volume and the possible error.

I know that  V = l × w × h.

But I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: You don't need derivatives for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Alter your volume formula to be the following

$V = (l \pm \epsilon) \times (w \pm \epsilon) \times (h \pm \epsilon)$

where $\epsilon$ is your error. You should get an upper bound (when you use the $+$) and a lower bound (when you use $-$).

Comment: Thanks Guy. Then...should I derivate?

Comment: There is no need to take the derivative if that is what you mean. The formula above gives both a lower and upper bound to what the volume can be if you just plug in the variables. I am not sure what you are asking.